# MS Project formula with access to predecessors field

Tags: ms-project

I have a project processed in Microsoft Project (in fact I am creating a template), tasks are connected on to another as I need them to be. I would like to add two new columns, namely start and finish day throughout the project.

Let me illustrate what I do need it for. I do have start and finish dates set and since all tasks are connected, I only need to set the first start date and all the others set automatically. These columns are going to be presented to team members as they do care about dates when they need to deliver the results.

In contrast, if I am presenting projects structure to a client, he/she cares about duration of a project in terms of man-days or days instead of some date (notion that task 1 happens from day 1 to day 10 of a project, after 16 days of a project tasks 5 and 6 are going to be executed are more important). So basically, I need a formula for new column (custom_start_field, custom_finish_field) which will take predecessors custom_finish_field fields (if not exists then 0), find out the latest and add 1 to it (now it is a custom_start_field), and then add duration of task + 1 and it becomes custom_finish_field.

Can any of you who are more experienced with MS Project help me? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Project 2007 defaults with columns for duration, start date and finish date for each task. I am not clear based on your question why this isn't adequate to meet the needs of the project team and sponsor.

Answer (score 0):

Inset a column called "Date1". Then right click on the column and select "Custom Fields".
Once the Custom Fields window pops up, locate "Custom Attributes" and click the "Formula..." button.

Once the Formula window opens, use the insert field drop-down to select the "Start" field in the "Date" section.  [Start] will populate the box.  Then type in "+ 1" after it. Click ok until you are back to your task sheet.  The "Date1" column should now show the date 1 day after the start date.

Do the same for the finish date.  Then you can right click and rename the columns as you see fit.  Hopefully this is what you were looking for.  If not, let me know and I will try to correct it.